# Type or namespace 'Mono' could not be found

Tags: .net, windows, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to simply compile code from here https://github.com/neoeinstein/purpleonion

I have installed mono, monodevelop, .net framework 4 and gtk#

When I open the solution and try to compile any of the projects, I get this error, namespace 'Mono' could not be found.

How can it not be found? Isn't that the base namespace that *must* exist in mono?

Comment: Make sure add the reference to the Mono dll files to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mono implementation of the BCL assemblies does not expose any additional API. If something's referring to a Mono namespace, it comes from another assembly, in this case Mono.Security.dll.

On Windows, MonoDevelop is capable of targeting either .NET or Mono. by default it targets .NET.

There are two ways you could fix this:

1. Install the Mono.Security.dll assembly into .NET, assuming it works there. You would do this for compile-time by placing it in an "assembly folder"
2. Set MonoDevelop to target the Mono framework using *Project->Target Runtime* or change the default in the *.NET Runtimes* options panel.

Comment: That did it! Specifically, number 2, which seems like the most natural way.