# The type or namespace 'Mono' could not be found in the global namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, mono, gtk#

I installed GTK# monodevelop and mono, I am using Xamarin to create a GTK# project

The similar question here has an answer which [does not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687997/type-or-namespace-mono-could-not-be-found)

whenever I try to debug the project i get told that 'The type or namespace 'Mono' could not be found in the global namespace'
[image]
I cant find Mono.dll to add to references.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got past it by installing the Nuget Addin (https://askubuntu.com/questions/481002/how-to-install-nuget-addin-for-monodevelop) and then using it to install Mono.Posix.